# Truecrypt FDE and BSOD dumping physical memory to disk - possible data leak?

Tags: disk-encryption, truecrypt, veracrypt

I'm not sure what dumping physical memory to disk during a BSOD does exactly, but is there a chance that it dumps all data from RAM to the HDD un-encrypted, because I doubt Truecrypt works during a BSOD? On the other hand if the whole disk is encrypted there is nowhere to dump that much data as the whole disk appears full and RAM is a few GB's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Most operating systems, including Windows, can be configured to write
>   debugging information and contents of the system memory to so-called
>   memory dump files (also called crash dump files) when an error occurs
>   (system crash, "blue screen," bug check). Therefore, memory dump files
>   may contain sensitive data. VeraCrypt cannot prevent cached passwords,
>   encryption keys, and the contents of sensitive files opened in RAM
>   from being saved unencrypted to memory dump files.

https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Memory%20Dump%20Files

This is no different for TrueCrypt.

As the links shows, memory dumps can be disabled.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering though how is it possible to write stuff to a fully encrypted HDD? Doesn't it appear full with no free space to write? How does Windows see the folder where to write the dump file, when everything is encrypted?

Comment: The OS does not talk to a process (they have been killed at the time of a BSOD) which does the encryption, but to a kernel driver. The driver acts as a layer between the OS and the disk driver. This remains active on a core dump.